# Cell content not showing up if heightForRowAtIndexPath is implemented

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using iOS 9.2 and XCode 7.2.

I have a basic `UITableView` object in which i add different kind of `UITableViewCell` subclasses.

With one of them, when i set manually the height overriding the method `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, i don't get any content on the cell.

If i return `-1` as height(the default value for the `UITable` row height), i get my cell showing up correctly. The thing is that i do need a different height for this row because the content is quite big.

here is the code for `heightForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MenuItem *menuItem = [menuManager menuItemAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([menuItem type] == MenuItemTypeEditorHeader) {
        return 100;
    } else {
        return [super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

`MenuItem` is a class containing the specific menu object' informations, such as the type. The result is that the cell is showed up at the correct height, but it's empty.

Comment: can you please add the code of the method heightForRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: add some part of code. so that we can explain you better.

Comment: why you added this line [super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: @RohitKP you're right, it's useless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not advisable to use `heightForRowAtIndexPath` anymore - thats old-school.  Instead, do this :

1. Set up **autolayout constraints** in your cell (if you dont know how to - you need to, its not something you can avoid anymore!)
2. Create an `estimatedRowHeight` for autolayout to use, on the `tableView`.  You can set it in the nib/storyboard or programmatically, in `viewDidLoad` for eg, like this :

self.tableview.estimatedRowHeight = 68.0;

3. Set your `tableview` to use 'automatic dimension', like this :

   self.tableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

And thats it.  If you do these things, then your cells will vary in height according to their constraints.  So if one of your subclasses has a height of 150px due to its constraints, that will work perfectly next to another subclass that has a height of 50px.  You can also vary the height of a cell dynamically depending on the contents of the cell, for eg when you have labels that expand using 'greater than or equal to' constraints.  Also - simply omit the '`heightForRowAtIndexPath`' method, you dont need to implement it at all.

Answer (score 0):

`HeightForRowAtIndexPath` just returns height of a row. So may be problem in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `tableView.reloadData()` ?

print the length of menu objects before you call `tableView.reloadData()`.